# "Wrong password" error on ssh server remotely

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

I am running an SSH server on my local machine and I am able to perfectly login and modify files if I use something like `myName@192.168.1.1` and type my password.

However, when I try to login from outside my local WiFi and type my actual IP address `myName@123.456.7.8` I just get a prompt message saying "Wrong password", even though it is the exact same username and password as I used locally within my home WiFi.

I have tried changing `PermitRootLogin` to `yes` and `PubKeyAuthentication` to `yes` as well but still have not luck with this issue.

Comment: Your *actual IP address* is your router -- everything on your LAN shares the router's address. If you are not *forwarding* port 22 to your server, then you are likely trying to login to your router..or wherever port 22 is being forwarded to.

Comment: both 123.456.7.8:22 and 123.456.7.8 return the same thing "wrong password" if I type in a different port then it says connection refused or device cannot be found I have the port set as the default 22 from sshd_config

Comment: Yes, but did you set the port forwarding rules in the router? That's what the first commented was about and your reply suggests you don't even know this.

Comment: yes I have is it the same as when doing a server for a game? just go on my ISP website and open the port? I have done that before for some games like minecraft and have done the same for port 22 not sure if this is what you meant

Comment: Not exactly but similar. And it's in the router such rules are defined. Whatever or not you can do it at the ISP website depends on the ISP, some actually allow this for all settings or only a partial set. Basically you want a rule that says port 22 requests are to be sent to a specific internal IP.

Comment: yeah so in my ISP(Optimum) website I go to port forwarding select my device local IP in this case 192.168.1.68 and select new rule port number 22 and it says rule 1 for port 22 but I still get the "wrong password" even after doing this and restarting the ssh server just in case